# List index out of range - Unable to strip user input

Tags: python

I am a newbie in Python and am just learning how to code. I have been working on a code that defines a function can trim a set of lines given in by the user and passes it onto another python script that calls it. The code is as follows:

```
import re 
import sys


def calltrimport():
        f=open("temp1.txt","w")
        print "Enter the complete call trace.\nMake Sure there are no extra or unnecessary white spaces in the content.\nPress Enter twice to finish input"
        file_lines = iter(raw_input, '') # Get lines as input until an empty line.
        file_content = '\n'.join(file_lines) # Join the file lines to one string, seperated by new-line.
        f.write(file_content)
        f.close()

        num_lines = 0
        with open("temp1.txt", 'r') as f:
                for line in f:
                        num_lines += 1

        print("Number of lines recorded in the entered text: ")
        print(num_lines)

        with open("temp1.txt","r") as f1:
                f2=open("temp2.txt","w")
                for content in range(0,num_lines):
                        try:
                                content = f1.readline()
                                sp = content.split('+')[0]
                                sp1 = sp.split('] ')[1]
                                sp1 = sp1.strip()
                                f2=open("temp2.txt","a")
                                f2.write(sp1+'\n')
                                f2.close
                        except IndexError, e:
                                print e
                                print "line = ", line
        with open('temp2.txt', 'r') as myfile:
                data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
        return data
```

I shall also put in a sample input and the expected output now:

```
Enter the complete call trace.
Make Sure there are no extra or unnecessary white spaces in the content.
Press Enter twice to finish input

[<ffffffffXXXXXXXX>] garbage1+0x268/0x360 [Nope]
[<ffffffffXXXXXXXX>] garbage2+0x412/0x470 [Nope]
[<ffffffffXXXXXXXX>] garbage3+0x761/0x9b0 [Nope]
[<ffffffffXXXXXXXX>] garbage4+0xfb/0x520 [Nope]
[<ffffffffXXXXXXXX>] garbage5+0x3c/0x3a0 [Nope]
[<ffffffffXXXXXXXX>] garbage6+0x65b/0xe00 [Nope]
[<ffffffffXXXXXXXX>] garbage7+0x139/0x580 [Nope]
[<ffffffffXXXXXXXX>] garbage8+0x1c0/0x1c0 [Nope]
[<ffffffffXXXXXXXX>] garbage9+0x20e/0x760 [Nope]
```

The expected output in file ***"temp2.txt"*** is supposed to look as follows:

```
garbage1
garbage2
garbage3
garbage4
garbage5
garbage6
garbage7
garbage7
garbage8
```

Instead, I get the following output:

```
Number of lines recorded in the entered call trace: 
9
list index out of range
line = [<ffffffffXXXXXXXX>] ? garbage1_+0x20e/0x760 [Nope]
list index out of range
line = [<ffffffffXXXXXXXX>] ? garbage1_+0x20e/0x760 [Nope]
list index out of range
line = [<ffffffffXXXXXXXX>] ? garbage1_+0x20e/0x760 [Nope]
list index out of range
line = [<ffffffffXXXXXXXX>] ? garbage1_+0x20e/0x760 [Nope]
list index out of range
line = [<ffffffffXXXXXXXX>] ? garbage1_+0x20e/0x760 [Nope]
list index out of range
line = [<ffffffffXXXXXXXX>] ? garbage1_+0x20e/0x760 [Nope]
list index out of range
line = [<ffffffffXXXXXXXX>] ? garbage1_+0x20e/0x760 [Nope]
list index out of range
line = [<ffffffffXXXXXXXX>] ? garbage1_+0x20e/0x760 [Nope]
list index out of range
line = [<ffffffffXXXXXXXX>] ? garbage1_+0x20e/0x760 [Nope]
```

Any idea as to where I'm calling an index beyond the bounds of my loop? I've wasted a lot of time on this and would really appreciate some help.

Edit:
Upon adding `raise` to the `except` block as advised by Klaus, I could see the following traceback:

```
Number of lines recorded in the entered call trace: 
9
list index out of range
line =  [<ffffffffXXXXXXXX>] ? some_garbage+0x20e/0x760 [Nope]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dts_check_final.py", line 13, in <module>
    mystr = ct_imp.calltrimport()
  File "/users/siddharath/dts/Final/ct_imp.py", line 26, in calltrimport
    sp1 = sp.split('] ')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Note: "dts_check_final.py" is from the python script that calls this on (ct_imp.py).

Comment: You should remove the `try` / `except` and see the full error traceback. You can add a simple `raise` to the `except` block to re-raise the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two days of losing my mind over the issue, I realized that *my raw input had "non-breaking-spaces" instead of "regular spaces"*. I realized this when I pasted the input in MS-Word and enabled the formatting characters display. To get around it, I explicitly set the default Python encoding to "UTF-8" by adding the following:

```
import sys
# encoding=utf8

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

And Viola! It works just fine.

Thanks for you help folks. And my apologies if the way I presented the question was somewhat incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately a guess (partly because you're printing `line` instead of `content` when there's an error), but could there be TAB characters in your input instead of spaces?  The failing

```
split('] ')[1]
```

means that the string `'] '` doesn't appear in (that part of) the line.

More generally: try rewriting this to not open any files at all (you already have all the strings in memory from the beginning).  The simplified dataflow should make it easier to debug.